# tightvnc configuration - software version check

Tags: software-installation, package-management, vnc

I have a raspberry pi and just managed to setup TightVNC running fine, but it looks like I can't use file transfer on the client. The viewer is 2.7 but I don't know what is my tightvncserver's version number.

How can I check a software's version number on Linux easily?

I used `apt-get install tightvncserver`... so everything was automatic but I guess would be great to track things back and see if I can do more. I'm on the command prompt so TightVNC doesn't have a GUI as far as I know for Linux - only the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache` to find out information about the various packages as you install them.

```
$ apt-cache show <package name>
```

#### Example

```
$ apt-cache show tightvncserver | grep Vers
Version: 1.3.9-6.4
```

The full output of `apt-cache show` is also quiet useful.

```
$ apt-cache show tightvncserver
Package: tightvncserver
Priority: optional
Section: universe/x11
Installed-Size: 1776
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Ola Lundqvist <opal@debian.org>
Architecture: amd64
Source: tightvnc
Version: 1.3.9-6.4
Provides: vnc-server, xserver
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libjpeg8 (>= 8c), libx11-6, zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), perl, x11-common | xserver-common, x11-utils, xauth
Recommends: xfonts-base, x11-xserver-utils
Suggests: tightvnc-java
Filename: pool/universe/t/tightvnc/tightvncserver_1.3.9-6.4_amd64.deb
Size: 835112
MD5sum: 78c295c9a39c3c62638ef58ac82b171f
SHA1: 73460682ed9705a73db15a5269239068e77620cb
SHA256: 7f5c9e47d0f5047426c4f09ff62971d6b1fb83ae8468251fa89ea08add08e500
Description-en: virtual network computing server software
 VNC stands for Virtual Network Computing. It is, in essence, a remote
 display system which allows you to view a computing `desktop' environment
 not only on the machine where it is running, but from anywhere on the
 Internet and from a wide variety of machine architectures.
 .
 This package provides a server to which X clients can connect and the
 server generates a display that can be viewed with a vncviewer.
 .
 The difference between the tightvncserver and the normal vncserver is the
 data encoding, optimized for low bandwidth connections. If the client do not
 support jpeg or zlib encoding it can use the default one. Later versions of
 vncserver (> 3.3.3r2) support a new automatic encoding that should be equally
 good as the tightvnc encoding.
 .
 Note: This server does not support or need a display. You need a vncviewer to
 see something. However, this viewer may also be on a computer running other
 operating systems in the local net.
Homepage: http://www.tightvnc.com
Description-md5: 212aadc6932fc1ffc49df1c9619bc26a
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```